# how to implements code for get the JSON objects in iphone?

Tags: iphone, json, ios5

hi all i am a new iphone developer. i am getting response from my required URL as shown in the below here i need to get Name of `"CategoryID":1` and Name of `"CategoryID":2` both are in separate array sets. how to implements code for get the JSON objects  in iphone?. thank you
code for getting response:

```
theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [RoutData mutableBytes] length:[RoutData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"---->>>>>>-->>>:%@",theXML);
```

**Response:**

```
LocationTracking[1807:f803] ---->>>>>>-->>>:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><getGearLockerCategoriesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><getGearLockerCategoriesResult><status>SUCCESS</status><errorType /><errorMessage /><jsonString>[{"CategoryID":1,"ItemCount":1,"level":1,"Name":"Boots","Description":"Boots descrition","childs":[{"CategoryID":2,"ItemCount":1,"level":2,"Name":"Cold Water","Description":"Cold Water Description","childs":[]}]}]</jsonString><serverTimestamp>63477507673796</serverTimestamp></getGearLockerCategoriesResult></getGearLockerCategoriesResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

<jsonString>

[{"CategoryID":1,"ItemCount":1,"level":1,"Name":"Boots","Description":"Boots 

descrition","childs":[{"CategoryID":2,"ItemCount":1,"level":2,"Name":"Cold 

Water","Description":"Cold Water Description","childs":[]}]}]

</jsonString>

<serverTimestamp>63477390375625</serverTimestamp>

</DiveTravelerResponse>
```

Comment: get all data in NSMutableDictionary and then set condition. on then basis of condition add in NSMutableArray Then get the value from array.

Answer (score 0):

The Touch JSON library is a good solution: https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON

Comment: I'd recommend `JSONKit` if you're going to bypass `NSJSONSerialization`.

Answer (score 0):

`NSJSONSerialization`. If your JSON is in an NSString named 'str':

```
NSError *jsonError = nil;
NSArray *rootObjectArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:&jsonError];
if (rootObjectArray)
{
   /* you have a foundation object */
}
else
{
   /* something went wrong */
   NSLog(@"jsonError: %@", [jsonError localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: hi friend i have used code your given Ans for my request but problem is when  i implemented code is like      
    NSError *jsonError = nil;
    NSArray *rootObjectArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[theXML dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:&jsonError]; but i am getting response like  2012-07-10 07:59:35.020 LocationTracking[1807:f803] ---******---:(null) how can solve the problem